# How to append multiple <li></li> elements to a <ul> in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to append two names to an unordered list in jQuery without editing the html or css.

My html looks like:

```
  <div class="col-md-6 yellow">
       <h2 id="yellowHeading">The Squad</h2>
       <ul id="yellowTeamList">

      </ul>
  </div>
```

I have tried:

```
$('#yellowTeamList').append('li').text('Joseph Banks');

$('#yellowTeamList').append('li').text('Simon Jones');
```

But it only appends the second name 'Simon Jones'.

[This is the code I have attempted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqRMO.png)

[This is the html I am trying to add the names to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yeg3P.png)

[This is my current output in a browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBgWi.png)

This is a very basic exercise after a lesson where they only taught us remove and append so the other examples Ive found are way too advanced for me to understand right now. Can anyone provide a beginner level answer?

Comment: Your `.append()` returns a reference to the original element. Therefore `.text()` is acting upon the `<ul>`, not the `<li>` you've just appended.

Comment: any idea on how I can get it inside the <li>? I'm not allowed to edit the html or css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `.text('blubb')` overwrites all content from the `<ul>` with "blubb". That's why in your case you only see the last name inside the `<ul>`

But you almost got it right.. try like so

```js
$('#yellowTeamList').append('<li>Joseph Banks</li>');
$('#yellowTeamList').append('<li>Simon Jones</li>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6 yellow">
   <h2 id="yellowHeading">The Squad</h2>
   <ul id="yellowTeamList">

   </ul>
</div>
```

it's only tagged jQuery but if you look at a vanilla js solution it may makes more sense in what you were trying to do

```js
//$('#yellowTeamList').append('<li>Joseph Banks</li>');
//$('#yellowTeamList').append('<li>Simon Jones</li>');

var teamList = document.querySelector('#yellowTeamList');

var liOne = document.createElement('li');
liOne.innerHTML = 'Joseph Banks';
teamList.append(liOne);

var liTwo = document.createElement('li');
liTwo.innerHTML = 'Simon Jones';
teamList.append(liTwo);
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 yellow">
   <h2 id="yellowHeading">The Squad</h2>
   <ul id="yellowTeamList">

   </ul>
</div>
```

and now you might think that's a lot of code, but you see there is the same things going on so you could place the repeated code into a function and the names in an array and then it would look like so:

```js
var teamList = document.querySelector('#yellowTeamList');

var writeNames = function(name) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = name;
    teamList.append(li);
};

['Joseph Banks', 'Simon Jones'].forEach(name => writeNames(name));
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 yellow">
   <h2 id="yellowHeading">The Squad</h2>
   <ul id="yellowTeamList">

   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! I didn't know I was thinking of the <li></li> being able to be a text insert. You saved me from future struggles! –